org.gnu.emacs - bwrap: Can't mount tmpfs on /newroot/tmp/.X11-unix: No such file or directory
I installed emacs using flatpak install flathub org.gnu.emacs. But when I try to run it, I get error. I am using Ubuntu via wsl2.  Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
$ flatpak list --app
Name                            Application ID        Version        Branch        Installation
Free Software Foundation        org.gnu.emacs         29.4           stable        user
$ flatpak run org.gnu.emacs
bwrap: Can't mount tmpfs on /newroot/tmp/.X11-unix: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

Good question to ask the people responsible for org.gnu.emacs

$flatpak run com.helix_editor.Helix gives
bwrap: Can't mount tmpfs on /newroot/tmp/.X11-unix: No such file or directory Now to ask where? com.helix_editor.Helix ? @DavidDE

I'm not too familiar with WSL2 or flatpak, but it sounds like you are trying to run X11 applications in a non-GUI environment. Have you actually configured WSL to support X11? Do other graphical applications work?

It is first time. I will see what you mentioned. thank you

Flatpak does not work well with wsl. Please use APT packages instead

If you want to run GUI apps with x11 in WSL, first install necessary dependencies with
sudo apt install x11-apps -y

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Sandboxed technologies like flatpak do not work well with wsl. Please use APT packages instead.
flatpak remove org.gnu.emacs
sudo apt install emacs


oh I see. Thanks for telling that.

If the solution works, you can accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark
